# Changes are not showing in github pages after pushing new code to the repository

Tags: next.js, deployment, github-actions, github-pages

I used github action to publish next.js app to the github pages. Then it created the nextjs.yaml file. But when I push new code the repository changes are not seen in the page. I even cloned the repository and pushed to the repository after changing some code. What should I do to make changes to the github pages after pushing code to the repository?